# numpy выдаёт nan для corrcoeff

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, numpy, nan

**numpy** отдаёт `nan`. Если есть два разных массива, то вылетают `nan`:

```
np.corrcoef([0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0.9, 0.9, 0.9])
array([[  1.,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan]])
```

Если два одинаковых массива, то этого не происходит:

```
np.corrcoef([0.1, 0.1, 0.1], [0.1, 0.1, 0.1])
array([[ 1.,  1.],
   [ 1.,  1.]])
```

Также непонятно, почему `corrcoef` отдаёт все `nan` для нулей:

```
np.corrcoef([0, 0, 0], [0.1, 0.1, 0.1])
array([[  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan]])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если смоделировать то что происходит [внутри функции `np.corrcoef()`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L2377-L2386):

```
In [37]: x=[0.1, 0.1, 0.1]; y=[0.9,0.9,0.9]

# расчет ковариционной матрицы    
In [38]: c = np.cov(x,y)

# для указанных значений - она имеет нулевые значения для 3-х из 4-х элементов
# в результате `np.corrcoef()` на месте этих элементов будут стоять NaN
In [39]: c
Out[39]:
array([[  2.88889492e-34,   0.00000000e+00],
       [  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00]])

In [40]: d = np.diag(c)

In [41]: d
Out[41]: array([  2.88889492e-34,   0.00000000e+00])

In [42]: stddev = np.sqrt(d.real)

In [43]: stddev
Out[43]: array([  1.69967494e-17,   0.00000000e+00])
```

В следующей строке мы получим `NaN` как результат деления на ноль:

```
In [44]: c /= stddev[:, None]
...\py36\Scripts\ipython3:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide

In [45]: stddev[:, None]
Out[45]:
array([[  1.69967494e-17],
       [  0.00000000e+00]])

In [46]: c
Out[46]:
array([[  1.69967494e-17,   0.00000000e+00],
       [             nan,              nan]])
```

Как это обойти - прибавить очень маленькое число к одному или нескольким элементам второго массива:

```
In [109]: x=[0.1, 0.1, 0.1]; y=[0.9,0.9,0.9+1e-16]

In [110]: np.corrcoef(x,y)
Out[110]:
array([[ 1.        , -0.57735027],
       [-0.57735027,  1.        ]])
```

или

```
In [111]: x=np.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1]); y=np.array([0.9,0.9,0.9])+1e-16

In [112]: np.corrcoef(x,y)
Out[112]:
array([[ 1., -1.],
       [-1.,  1.]])
```